# Kubernetes Installation on Mac/Vagrant/Parallels

Tags: vagrant, fedora, kubernetes, parallels

Originally posted on [github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/13608).

Following [instructions](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/vagrant.html), using:

Mac OSX 10.10.5
Vagrant 1.7.4
Parallels Desktop 10.2.2

When I run

```
export VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER=parallels
export KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=vagrant
./cluster/kube-up.sh
```

master and minion-1 windows pop up, apparently fully functional (I can ssh into them and everything seems to work) but the command line shows following problems for both master and minion:

```
==> master: Checking for Parallels Tools installed on the VM...
==> master: Parallels Tools installed on this VM are outdated! In most cases
==> master: this is fine but in rare cases it can cause things such as shared
==> master: folders to not work properly. If you see shared folder errors,
==> master: please update Parallels Tools within the virtual machine and 
==> master: reload your VM.
```

```
master: Running: /var/folders/ng/8c3_08cd5nb8y8414tffrb980000gn/T/vagrant-shell20150904-29622-1bot2j5.sh
==> master: Job for network.service failed. See 'systemctl status network.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
==> master: An error occurred. The error will be shown after all tasks complete.
```

I have applied the fedora repo fix recommended [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/8019) but it didn't help.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Grant it when I tried installing kubernetes on parallels, it was version 0.13, but it was a total nightmare, I ended up switching to vmware and creating a coreos vagrant box that runs the parts of kubernetes in systemd, and that worked like a charm ever since.  Which part of the issue was the coreos box for parallels is/was ancient.

Comment: I've been using VirtualBox + Vagrant + OS X 10.10.5 without issue.

Comment: Yes, I had to switch to VirtualBox as well. The only minor problem I'm experiencing with VB is initial salt provisioning failure during `kube-up.sh`. But, if I wait for few minutes and run `kube-up.sh` again, it succeeds.

Comment: please paste 'systemctl status network.service' output log